# Trying to change object property and keep reactivity. Property or method "vm" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Until now, I was trying to change the value of an object property to false using `@click='review.isActive = true'`, however, it turns out Vue cannot detect such changes which means that property won't be reactive.

Based on the documentation https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats, this can be avoided by using one of the following methods:

```
Vue.set(vm.reviews, index, true)

vm.reviews.splice(index, 1, true)
```

Sadly I get an error using either way. I assume I don't quite understand how the Vue instance works and I'm trying to access it when I shouldn't be able to.

I assume Vue/vm are supposed to be the Vue instance but I can't seem to access it.

In both cases, I get error "Property or method "vm"/"Vue" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render."

I'm using Vue webpack-simple webpack template and my Vue instance seems to be initialized in main.js file like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
    store: store,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

The file in which the array manipulation is happening is different and a component.

Comment: _"it turns out Vue cannot detect such changes"_  that's only true if the `isActive` property of `review` is not initially defined in `data`

Comment: _"I'm using Vue webpack-simple webpack template"_  otherwise known as the old / outdated / legacy Vue CLI v2 implementation. [Vue CLI v3](https://cli.vuejs.org/) is the new hotness

Comment: Your question shows `review` and `reviews`. Is there a `v-for` involved?

Comment: Yes, the @click='review.isActive = true' is inside a v-for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `review` object is an item in your `reviews` array and that they do not initially have an `isActive` property but you'd like to add one, you can use `vm.$set` to add a new reactive property.

For example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    reviews: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Review #1'
    },{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Review #2'
    },{
      id: 3,
      name: 'Review #3'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="review in reviews" :key="review.id">
    <p>
      Review {{ review.name }} status: 
      <code>{{ review.isActive ? 'ACTIVE' : 'INACTIVE' }}</code>
    </p>
    <button @click="$set(review, 'isActive', true)">Activate</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the use of `$set` in the `@click` handler.

---

From the comment below, if you wanted to add new properties after the data is retrieved, do it before you assign the value to your data property, eg

```js
this.reviews = data.from.somewhere.map(review => ({...review, isActive: false}))
```

If you must add the new property *after* the data is assigned, you need to use `vm.$set` to make it reactive

```js
this.reviews.forEach(review => {
  this.$set(review, 'isActive', false)
})
```

Once these properties are added reactively, you can go back to simply changing them without `$set`

```html
<button @click="review.isActive = true">
```

Comment: Well the thing is all my reviews come from Google so I make a GET request for the reviews and then do this --- this.reviews = response.data.result.result.reviews --- and --- this.reviews.map(o => o.isActive = false). They don't have an isActive property originally, I just map it myself.

Comment: What do you mean? The objects originally come without a isActive property and after I run the map function, they receive one. I confirmed it by running console.log(this.reviews) before the map function and after that to see if the property is created.

Comment: @Bobimaru I misunderstood what you were doing (comments are not good for adding code) but I've now updated my answer

Comment: Thanks to your explanations and code, I realized what I was doing wrong. Your code also helped me clean up mine a bit by removing redundant stuff ( like the map function ). Thanks you a lot, I appreciate the help.